# How to assign param value to a string variable in loadrunner

Tags: string, loadrunner

Can we assign param value to a string variable?
For example:
`web_reg_save_param_ex("paramname=p","LB={something}", "RB={something}", LAST);`

How can we store `p` value in a string variable.

Comment: Are you looking to store a Loadrunner variable value in a C string?

Comment: Yes #James Can we do that?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of ways to move from a LoadRunner variable to a C string...... How familiar are you with the language of the tool, C?

Comment: Ok.. Coming to C language I can say I am an intermediate programmer

Comment: #James can you please tell me how to move a parameter from a LoadRunner to a string variable.

Comment: did anyone come right with this?I am struggling with it as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

You can use utility function(lr_save_string() and lr_eval_string()).

web_reg_save_param_ex("paramname=p","LB={something}", "RB={something}", LAST);

lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{p}"),"localVariable");

Comment: Isn't this more or less a loop action? lr_save_string creates a parameter just like the one web_reg_save_param_ex does? I.e. not a C string like the one the original post requested.

Answer (score 0):

- strcpy()
- strncpy()
- sprintf() ...